# Utilizing 5 physical servers in 1 cluster

Tags: mysql

I have 5 physical servers with low end memory & cpu resources. I want to create 1 cluster using all these servers and want to run mysql db on the same such that mysql db would utilize 5 server's CPU power to execute db queries & same for memory. Could you please help me understanding how to achieve this?

Regards,

Comment: I think you're likely to do better asking this question over at ServerFault: http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that MySQL clustering is primarily for [availability](http://www.mysql.com/products/database/cluster/faq.html#11), not performance. With low end servers, your performance will not be nearly as good as one server with the same aggregate cpu/memory resources.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been finding with my tests on MySQL Cluster. Writes are really fast and seem to scale up with the number of nodes (and the fact that NDB is in-memory). But reads are slower than plain MySQL (though MySQL Cluster does seem to aggressively cache read results.) But biggest upside with MySQL Cluster is HA.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't scale up like that. The only effective way to scale up MySQL's performance is more memory.

However, if you have the resources to re-tool your application and your database will partition well at the table level, then it's possible to have your app connect to multiple databases depending on what tables it needs. You basically will want an ORM layer (such as Hibernate) that can be taught to associated an object's table with a particular database.